# find a counterexample to show it is not bounded

Tags: analysis

Let $a < b$ and $f : (a,b) \rightarrow R$  be a continuous function that is locally bounded.
Does it follow that f is bounded on (a,b)? Give arguments for your answer.

I was thinking that it should be that $f$ is not bounded on (a,b).It can be prove by counterexample. Could somebody help me find a counterexample?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: try a function that goes to $\infty$ as you approach one of the endpoints.

Comment: Does $f(x)=\frac1x$ on $(0,1)$ work? It is continuous but not bounded. I'm unsure about the locally bounded part...